# Как отключить scroll при рендеринге страницы в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Когда искал ответ на свой вопрос, люди пишут что им наоборот нужен скролл вверх, потому что скролл остается на месте. Как они это сделали? Вообщем делаю сайт, где есть блок с фильтрами, когда нажимаю на фильтр он добавляется или убирается из url страницы, и в этот момент происходит скролл вверх. Кто знает как это отключить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте закинуть код в песочницу. По вышеприведенному скриншоту и описанию ничего нельзя сказать определенного

Comment: Такое ощущение, что при простановке "галочек" у вас происходит не скролл, а обновление страницы. По умолчанию, если изменить url, то пойдет "обновление" по новому url

Comment: В песочницу пока что сложно будет закинуть, тк товары, фильтры и сама страница с категориями генерируются по информации с базы данных. Что на счет обновления страницы по новому url, да скорее всего это оно и есть, но если посмотреть похожие магазины, у них когда нажимаешь на фильтр, обновляется url а скролл остается на месте

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page